# How do you use the navsat_transform set_datum service?

Tags: navigation, navsat-transform-node, rosservice, navsat-transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use `navsat_transform` and I'm having difficulty with the global frame origin not matching the latitude and longitude I'm setting it to in the launch file. For more on *that* particular problem, see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/237305/localisation-inaccurate-and-mapodom-frames-origins-move/).

So I want to use the navsat_transform `set_datum` service to manually set the origin, as described in the [GPS Integration tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration). However the link to the robot_localization/SetDatum service message is broken (try it [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/robot_localization/html/msg/SetDatum.html)) and I can't find anything about it in the source API.

I've tried:

```
rosservice call /set_datum <tab>
```

Like a conventional set_pose service, but that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to use the set_datum service correctly? Or otherwise manually change it after launch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237947/how-do-you-use-the-navsat_transform-set_datum-service?/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just

```
rosservice call /datum <tab>
```

is ok.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

asimat_y's answer is correct, but I'll restate the problem and solution in greater detail to better document the problem.

## Problem

The pose and origin of `/map` frame (as created by `navsat_transform`) is not where you want or expect it to be. E.g:

[image: map_and_odom]

This is the robot just after boot. The frame in the top-left is `/map` which should be right under the robot because the robot is currently sitting on the lattitude/longitude the `/map` origin should be fixed to.

## Cause

The pose and origin of `/map` can be set using the 'datum' ros parameter in a launch file for `navsat_transform`. However, for reasons I don't quite understand, if you run this launch file on your robot when the robot boots (and sometimes when you run the launch file after boot-up as well) the origin and orientation may not be correct.

There may be other reason for changing the pose e.g. you want to reset it in the field.

## Solution

The set_datum service can be used to manually reset the orientation and origin of `/map`. To do this open a terminal (making sure your ROS environment variables are configured!) and type:

```
rosservice call /datum <tab>
```

You should then see something like this:

```
user@robot_ip_address:~$ rosservice call /datum "geo_pose:
position:
    latitude: 0.0           
    longitude: 0.0          
    altitude: 0.0
orientation:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 0.0"
```

Fill out all the relevant parameters and then press `enter` to set the new origin and orientation. Remember that for the orientation you must have w = 1.0 at a minimum! (x,y,z,w = 0 will result in a NAN error). Verify that this worked by checking your frames again, e.g.

[image: map]

Now `/map` is correctly set to the latitude/longitude that the robot is currently sitting on.

You can also call the set_datum service from a file and change it that way. This is preferable if you want to reset the datum regularly. To do this in a python script, use the following code:

```
from geographic_msgs.msg import GeoPose
from robot_localization.srv import *

rospy.wait_for_service('datum')
try:
    geo_pose = rospy.ServiceProxy('datum', SetDatum)
    response = geo_pose(newMapPose)
except rospy.ServiceException, e:
    rospy.loginfo ("Service call failed: %s"%e)
```

Where `newMapPose` is a [GeoPose](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geographic_msgs/html/msg/GeoPose.html) message containing the coordinates you want to reset your frame origin to.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2016-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2